# Allow only local requests to use HTTP, all other redirected to HTTPS, in IIS 7

Tags: iis, http, redirect, https

I have a app that runs on the web server that needs to post back to a site. It will only work locally over http. Now all requests are set to redirect to https if http is used. Is there any way to allow only local requests to use http while still redirecting all other http requests to the https site?

Im using a custom error page on 403.4 errors to redirect users currently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [IIS Url Rewrite module](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-the-url-rewrite-module) and write whatever rules you need to support the scenarios you want to setup.